# Angular Universal doesn't serve static assets

Tags: node.js, angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I run simple [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) SSR (server-side rendering) application, everything works fine, server renders html but there is one problem. static assets, like fonts, images, icons doesn't get loaded by server, but browser. What I want to do, is to render html with static assets.

I tried `express.static()` function but couldn't make it work. So how can I make it work?

Comment: Did you find the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by suggestions [here](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/858).

Implement HTTP interceptor according to [this article](https://bcodes.io/blog/post/angular-universal-relative-to-absolute-http-interceptor). It will add absolute url to all requests with a relative path, so SSR with server running will work. But while static pre-rendering `this.request` will be empty, in this case you should redirect such requests to your own static server, e.g. `http://localhost:3000`

Create NodeJs script for pre-rendering. It will run [static server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-serving-static-files-in-express#step-3-%E2%80%94-creating-your-express-server) on port 3000 (the same port as in interceptor), when it's running, you can execute `npm run prerender` in [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options). Then listen to events `error` and `close` on the subprocess and close server when they happen:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

// In static server 'listen' callback
const sp = spawn('npm', ['run', 'prerender'], { stdio: 'inherit', timeout: 5 * 60 * 1000 })
sp.on('error', (err) => {
    // Pre-rendering failed.
    // TODO kill subprocess, close server, end current process with error code
});
sp.on('exit', (code: number) => {
  // Pre-rendering is finished
  // TODO Close server
  
  if (code !== 0) {
    // Pre-rendering failed.
    // TODO End current process with error code
  }
})
```